How to create a cicular hole pattern with geometry nodes (flange hole pattern)?
It is asked to create a procedural circular hole pattern that should look like so:

The setup should not be done with booleans to get a clean topology. The inner holes (B) can always be 6-sides, as shown here:

This setup can be achieved by using this setup, but the gaps (A) still remain

Is there a way to either Fix the gaps (A) with clean topology (e.g. Quadrilateral mesh node), or to use a better setup?
Thank you in advance!

I know you said you do not want to use Mesh Boolean to keep a clean topology... but if you choose the right settings I see no reason why you should not get a clean topology?

Or if you want an edge running through the center of the ring:

Or like your reference with 10 holes in the ring, everything non-destructive and adjustable:

Sure, these examples have n-gons... but if you go for holes with less vertices like in your lower screenshot, you can maybe find settings to have it with quads as well. Personally I would rather go for the n-gon approach with still very clean topology.

Here's a fun idea: use a cone and delete some faces. Subdivision Surface will make circles out of them for you. Or ellipses. Or more like egg shapes: . It is a little bit of a joke, but maybe you could use it if you wanted to shade with respect to radial and in-out directions and don't mind the awkward quads which touch holes with only one vert:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)

Imgur mirror
You need to adjust the "Radius Top" of the cone to the number of holes to make the holes roughly circular. Also for a small number of holes, the minimum radius top is too big, because it controls the top vertices which get deleted, so you would need to use non-zero "Radius Top" and only delete the top face instead of vertices.

Imgur mirror
You can make the holes perfectly circular, but you need to calculate their respective centers, then distribute the angles evenly, move all verts to average distance to hole center and maybe blur positions (pinning boundaries) afterwards...

With good topology:

After subdivision:

General setup (create instances of a plane+hole and rotate around):

Get dimensions setup (pretty straightforward, wheren X_Hole is the radius from the center of the flange to the center of the holes)

The core part: create a plane with a hole:

The creation is extruding from a circle, so topology is perfect.
One frame transforms the circle extrusion into a square
Another frame makes X of the square be the radius, and Y of the square be the angle of rotation (we will convert these coordinates to polar)


Convertion to polar setup:



Oh Man, thank you so much for this greatanswer! This is more than i expected, the issue is perfectly solved. One final Question tough: If you change the Number of verts in the "Mesh Circle" Node in the "Make plane Hole" Group to any value that is not 8, the mesh no longer works. This is because the Plane needs 8 verts to form a correct rectangle, is that right? Anyway, thanks again an greetings from Germany!

@pixelpoems.de, yes. I made it exactly with 8 for topology, thinking that 4 connects to the corners of the square and 4 to the centers of the edges of the squares. If you change that number, you will need to find other solutions to transform the extruded circle into a square.
